# How to go back to the old UI on GitHub

Tags: github, user-interface

It looks like Microsoft has just toggled a new look and feel for GitHub that just recently was available in Feature preview section.

Is there an option to switch it back to the old UI? It looks like this switch to the new UI is enforced and I can't find a way to disable it.

Comment: As far as I know there is not an option to switch back. I did find this extension for Chrome and Firefox: https://github.com/daattali/oldschool-github-extension. It reverts some aspects of the old ui, but not everything. Maybe it's what you're looking for.